# Are $W$ and $L$ Subspaces of $V$ or not.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I solves my homework, And I need to tell me if it is true or not please. My professor is very carful, so if there exist any simple mistake tell me please.
(Sorry, I don’t speak English well)

> Let $V=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}} =\lbrace f|f :\mathbb{R}\rbrace$ be the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$. Then V is a vector space on $\mathbb{R}$ under the following operations: For every $f, g \in V$ and $r \in R$, $f +g$ and $rf$ are the functions from $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ that are given by $(f +g)(x) = f (x)+g(x)$ and $(rf)(x) = r(f(x))$ for all $x \in R$.
>
> a) if $W=\lbrace f \in V \ | \ f \ is \ continues \ at \ 0 \rbrace$, determine whether $W$ is a subspace of $V$ or not (justify your answer).

It's clear $\phi \neq W$ (since -for example- $x\in W$ ), and $W\subseteq V$ (how can i prove that?), Suppose that $f,g \in W$, and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

$(\alpha f+g)(0)=(\alpha f)(0)+g(0)$

$=\alpha f(0)+g(0)$

$=\alpha \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)+\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$

$=\lim_{x \to 0} (\alpha f)(x)+\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$

$=\lim_{x \to 0} (\alpha f+g)(x)$

since $(\alpha f+g)(0)=\lim_{x \to 0} (\alpha f+g)(x)$

Hence,$(\alpha f+g)$ is continuous at $0$, then $(\alpha f+g) \ \in W$.

$W$ is a subspace of $V$.

> b) if $L=\lbrace f \in V \ | \ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\infty \rbrace$, determine whether $L$ is a subspace of $V$ or not (justify your answer).

Suppose that $f,g \in L$, and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

$\lim_{x \to \infty} (\alpha f+g)(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty} (\alpha f)(x)+\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$

$=\alpha \lim_{x \to \infty} (f)(x)+\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$

$=\infty$

since $\lim_{x \to \infty} (\alpha f+g)(x)=\infty$, then $(\alpha f+g)(x) \in L$.

$W$ is a subspace of $V$

> c) if $f=7-\sqrt{3} x sin^2 (x)$, $g_1(x)=5x,\ g_2(x)=8, \ g_3(x)=xcos^2(x), \ e^x$ are elements in $V$, show that $f$ is a linear combination of $g_1,\ g_2,\ g_3$ and $g_4$.

we will consider if there exist $c_1, \ c_2, \ c_3,\ c_4 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$f(x)=c_1 g_1(x)+c_2 g_2(x)+c_3 g_3(x)+c_4 g_4(x)$

this means that we will seek $c_1, \ c_2, \ c_3,\ c_4 \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying that

$7-\sqrt{3} x \sin ^2 (x)=5c_1 x+8c_2+c_3 x\cos ^2(x)+c_4 e^x$

$=5c_1 x+8c_2+c_3 x(1-\sin ^2(x))+c_4 e^x$

$=5c_1 x+8c_2+c_3 x-c_3 x \sin ^2(x)+c_4 e^x$

$=(5c_1+c_3) x+8c_2-c_3 x \sin ^2(x)+c_4 e^x$

Therefore, we will search for $c_1, \ c_2, \ c_3,\ c_4 \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying that

$5c_1+c_3=0$, $8c_2=7$, $c_3=\sqrt{3}$, $c_4=0$

As a result, $c_1=\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{5}$, $c_2=\frac{7}{8}$, $c_3=\sqrt{3}$, $c_4=0$.

Hence $c_1=\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{5}$, $c_2=\frac{7}{8}$, $c_3=\sqrt{3}$, $c_4=0$, makes $f(x)$ a linear combination of $g_1(x), \ g_2(x), \ g_3(x), \ g_4(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Correct.

b) What you wrote works only for $\alpha>0$. 
(What is the zero vector of $V$?)

c) Correct. However, starting from one side, piece by piece exchanging the terms, and arriving to the other side might be a cleaner approach:
$x=\frac15g_1(x)$
$x\sin^2(x)\ =\ x(1-\cos^2(x))\ =\ x-x\cos^2(x)\ =\ \frac15g_1(x)-g_3(x)$
$\dots$

Comment: Thank you so much, you are right.

b) what about that:

Let $f(x) \in L$,
and take for example $\alpha =-1 \in \mathbb{R}$ 

$lim_{x \to \infty} (\alpha f)(x)=lim_ {x \to \infty} (-f(x))=-lim_ {x \to \infty} f(x)=-\infty$

So, $\alpha f \notin L$

There exist $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha f \notin
 L$.

Then $L$ is not a subspace of $V$.

Comment: Yes, good. Even easier: the zero element (=constant 0) is not in $L$.

Comment: Thank you so much.